# Is there any API in Java to access wikipedia data

Tags: java, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want to know: is there any API or a query interface through  which I can access Wikipedia data?

Answer (score 22):

[Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/), the wiki platform that wikipedia uses does have an HTTP based API. See [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query).

For example, to get pages with the title stackoverflow, you call

`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stackoverflow`

There are some (incomplete) Java wrappers around the API - [see the Client Code - Java](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_Code#Java) section of the API page for more detail.

Answer (score 8):

For the use with Java, try http://code.google.com/p/wiki-java. It is only one class, but a great one!

Answer (score 5):

**You can use [Jwiki](https://github.com/viralvaghela/Jwiki) to get Wikipedia data**
Example :

```
Jwiki jwiki = new Jwiki("elon musk");
System.out.println("Title :"+jwiki.getDisplayTitle()); //get title
System.out.println("Text : "+jwiki.getExtractText());  //get summary text
System.out.println("Image : "+jwiki.getImageURL());    //get image URL
```

Comment: Man You Rocked It Best API ever

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and the closest I came to an out-of-the-box solution is bliki, hosted at http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/.
I also wrote an article at Integrating Stuff to help you get started with it: http://www.integratingstuff.com/2012/04/06/hook-into-wikipedia-using-java-and-the-mediawiki-api/

Answer (score 2):

[MediaWiki is a free and open-source wiki software. Originally developed by Magnus Manske and improved by Lee Daniel Crocker, it runs on many websites, including Wikipedia, Wiktionary and Wikimedia Commons.[5][6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

There is list of Java libraries that can help you to connect wiki by java code .
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java

but after use some of them because of their limitations , we try to call REST services from mediawiki directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wikipedia4j](https://github.com/llmjava/wikipedia4j) to search for documents like this

```java
Wikipedia wiki = new Wikipedia();
List<Document> results = wiki.search("apple");
for(Document doc: results) {
  System.out.println(doc);
}
```