# JAVA API for Wikipedia

Tags: java, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

is there any (JAVA) API for polling Wikipedia for data about a specified person or anything else ? Any other such API would be useful.

Example - search for Michael Jackson

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397938/is-there-any-api-in-java-to-access-wikipedia-data), but this does not seem to address this query.

Comment: i too mentioned the link. have a look again

Comment: I don't see how the answers at that link don't help you... please explain.

Comment: How can i fetch data about a person say Michael Jackson ? I see nothing like this over there. If you do please post it as a comment or as an answer. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Michael%20Jackson is one example.

Comment: http://www.integratingstuff.com/2012/04/06/hook-into-wikipedia-using-java-and-the-mediawiki-api/ is another example... substitute Michael Jackson for Web Service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To query the raw page:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Michael%20Jackson

**To query the page in XML or JSON:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Michael%20Jackson

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Michael%20Jackson

---

For more information on the API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Thanks ! but i need to consume this response, so something in xml or json format would be better.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. @AnkitRustagi